# What does "heroku keys:add" do?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, heroku, devops

The heroku keys:add is a command that comes up frequently when reading about heroku on the internet.

What does it do exactly?

Comment: Give the googles a go with `heroku keys:add`. It's the first hit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's used to upload your public key if you are using SSH instead of HTTP as your git transport.

> If you don’t already use SSH and if you want to use SSH Git transport
>   on Heroku, you’ll need to create a public/private key pair to deploy
>   code. This keypair is used for the strong cryptography and that
>   uniquely identifies you as a developer when pushing code changes.

[Documentation](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/keys)